# Is it possible to select some specific columns when querying using Object.find_by_ColumnName method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The xxx.find_by_xxx method seems select all the columns from a record, it will cost more unnecessary resource when dealing with a table with lots of columns. Is there any way to select the only columns that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add :select attribute:

```
Note.find_by_name("Test", :select => "notes.id,notes.name")
```